# rangeslider with feedback of target and current value

Tags: javascript, css, html

i've seen a marketing video of a home automation system.
in this video at 0:10 -> 0:12 they are showing a rangeslider where the person can adjust a for example a temperature. The current value is shown  behind with a dashed background. The Targetvalue is adjusted with the dot.

so the function in this slider is to show the targetvalue with the position of the dot and the current value with the dashed background.

Link Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMFkHs41ZR8

Can somebody with experience in CSS can give me a tip for what i should search in the web to realize something similiar with CSS and HTML5?

Thanks for your support.

greetings
Michael

Comment: Search : "[HTML 5 range slider](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTML%205%20range%20slider&rct=j#q=HTML+5+range+slider)". There are some [cool examples here](http://codepen.io/collection/DgYaMj/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a css solution but a plugin that I have found useful. https://refreshless.com/nouislider/ 
This does have options to bind a text readout (like on the side of the slider in the video) to the slider value/values. Those text readouts could also be bound to another input(like live data instead of the target value the slider is displaying).

Hope this helps!

Comment: So you mean. That i can manipulate the background with a Second input?

Comment: I just watched the video again and I am not sure this plugin has exactly what you need built in automatically. I thought you were talking about the slider pips. But it seems like it could be MacGyvered. You could overlay 2 sliders where the top one is the one that the user adjusts and the bottom one would represent the actual data. You could change the css (or choose a different template) so that the slider colors are different. Then you could change the slider handles on the background slider to display: none with some Javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks. Maybe there is another slider plugin. Or does somebody has tried sonething before and can help.